# Bug Wordpress WP Bakery tabs

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wpbakery

I have a problem with the tabs of WP Bakery, can not change tabs, the click is inactive and I have an error js:

```
$ us.WTabs is undefined
```

Could someone have a similar problem and help me?

https://www.dejean-drapeaux.com/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: where exactly is the tab group located in your page? I can't see it

Comment: Thank for the reply.
Les tabs sont visibles à cette Url : https://www.dejean-drapeaux.com/univers/

Comment: there's an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined` referring to `$us.wTabs`, but then I can see the property via console once the page is loaded. Is it possible that you must wait `document::ready` before firing the script?

Comment: confirmed: if I copy and past the `wTabs` script (line 205 through line 283 of your html source) in my console, tabs start working.

Answer (score 0):

you are facing an issue with WPBakery Page Builder functionality, 
I would recommend you to open a ticket via it’s support portal:

http://support.wpbakery.com/